# IP addresses doesn't work as scope in custom rule

Tags: windows-firewall

i changed remote port in registry on win server 2012.
i want specific specific IPs can be used to remote by this port.
For this reason,I create a rule in firewall and allow this port and in scope tab added IPs in remote section but this not working(all IPs can remote to this server).
Description:
win server 2019 is server.I change remote port (3389) to y(in registry). I have PC1,PC2(clients). I want only PC1 to be able to remote to server (with MSTSC)in my entire network and others can't.
please help me
thanks

Comment: What programs? What port? Which services? How is it failing?

Comment: win server 2019 is server.I change remote port (3389) to y(in registry). I have PC1,PC2(clients). I want only PC1 to be able to remote to server (with MSTSC)in my entire network and others can't

Comment: Use the EDIT button to add this and any other helpful or relevant information to your question, improving it. Adding info in comments does not really improve your question in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, it solved! Despite the several times I had done gpupdate and reset the server
And he did not answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).